# Are questions about International Sport Federations decisions on-topic on Politics.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am thinking about large organizations like [FIFA](http://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/who-we-are/) who have a great influence in sports and deal with lots of money at global level. I expect that many of its mechanisms to resemble those found in political organizations, as they also seem to have ties with some of these (e.g. [United Nations](http://www.fifa.com/governance/news/y=2018/m=3/news=fifa-president-meets-with-united-nations-secretary-general.html)).

**Question:** Are questions about International Sport Federations on-topic on Politics.SE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions should always be asked on the stackexchange site where they are the most on-topic.

[Sports Stackexchange](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) already has a tag about the [FIFA](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa), and there are several questions which are more about the people in suits than about the people in shirts. When you have a question about the internal workings of a sport organization, you will likely find more knowledgeable people on Sports SE.

What I would consider more on-topic on Politics SE is where sport organizations and international politics interact with each other. For example [when politicians hand out bribes to sport organizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_Winter_Olympic_bid_scandal) or [when sport events get boycotted for political reasons](http://www.goal.com/en/news/will-england-boycott-world-cup-2018-in-russia/qjxxn4kdy3pn1uwjtx3rh5p99).